# Broadcasting data not passed

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make an app that tracks device's location using a service and display that location on Google Map. But I feel like the code in service is not executed at all. When I try to retrieve and assign latitude and longitude to a LatLng object I cannot because they are null.

Here is the main activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1001;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    private LatLng currentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (isServicesOK()) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        }
        getLocationPermission();
        startMyService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: resumed from service");
        if (mBroadcastReceiver == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume: broadcastReceiver == null");
            mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: receiving current location");
                    currentLocation = new LatLng((double) intent.getExtras().get("latitude"),
                            (double) intent.getExtras().get("longitude"));
                }
            };
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume:"+ currentLocation.toString());
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
        if(mBroadcastReceiver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        }

    }

    private void startMyService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startMyService: starting to track devices location");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            moveCamera(currentLocation, 15f);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // auto-generated permission check
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isServicesOK(){
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");
        int availvable = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MapsActivity.this);

        if(availvable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //everything is fine
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: google play services is working");
            return true;
        }

        else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(availvable)) {
            //an error occured but we can resolve it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MapsActivity.this,availvable, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST); dialog.show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"You can't make map request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("location");
                        intent.putExtra("latitude", currentLocation.getLatitude());
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", currentLocation.getLongitude());
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                    }
                }
            });

        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to get the current location and update the map but without using a service. But I need to make it this way - with a service. And I can't figure out where my mistake is.